# How to read hex values from file into byte array?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, filereader

I have a file which consists of comments (look like Java single-line comments which start with double slash, `//`) and space-separated hex values.

File looks like this:

```
//create applet instance
0x80 0xB8 0x00 0x00 0x0c 0x0a 0xa0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x62 0x03 0x01 0xc 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x7F;
```

How can I convert line where hex values go from string to byte array?

I use the following approach:

```
List<byte[]> commands = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
      String line = fileReader.nextLine();
      if (line.startsWith("0x")) {
          commands.add(line.getBytes());
      }
}
```

But definitely, this shows a byte representation of symbols as they were chars and doesn't convert it to byte. That's right. But how can it be converted properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you do it on paper, or in your head? I would ignore the ; at the end of the line, I would split the string on spaces, I would ignore the 0x prefixes, and I would parse each hex number into a byte. That's also what your program needs to do.

Comment: Just as an aside, [`Integer.parseInt(String,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,int)) will parse hex strings.  It won't parse the `0x` so you'll need to strip that part off, and the space too.

Comment: Yes, this came to my mind too. But I thought  Java has some util methods that parse a string containing hex values.

Comment: @markspace You can use the `Integer::decode` and it will deal with choosing a radix based on the prefix for you.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I forgot that `Integer` has a method which gets radix.

Comment: The problem in converting to integer and then to byte.  I'm not sure if it will be very efficient. I will think how to do it in some elegant way.

Comment: @mypetlion why not use `Byte::decode`?

Comment: @mypetlion Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't realize `Integer` had such a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just thought I'd point out that if you loosen the specification a little bit, you can essentially do this in one line with `splitAsStream`.

```
List<Integer> out = Pattern.compile( "[\\s;]+" ).splitAsStream( line )
       .map( Integer::decode ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

I use Integer here and `Integer::decode` because `Byte::decode` will throw an error on `0x80`, the OP's first input.  And you'd have to do a bit more work if you really need an array of primitives, but often boxed numbers will do in practice.

Here's the whole code:

```
public class ScannerStream {

   static String testVector = "//create applet instance\n" +
"0x80 0xB8 0x00 0x00 0x0c 0x0a 0xa0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x62 0x03 0x01 0xc 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x7F;";

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      List<List<Integer>> commands = new ArrayList<>();
      Scanner fileReader = new Scanner( new StringReader( testVector ) );
      while( fileReader.hasNextLine() ) {
         String line = fileReader.nextLine();
         if( line.startsWith( "0x" ) ) {
            List<Integer> out = Pattern.compile( "[\\s;]+" ).splitAsStream( line )
                    .map( Integer::decode ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
            System.out.println( out );
            commands.add( out );
         }
      }
      System.out.println( commands );
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I also faced with an error using `Byte::decode`. Great solution, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. Just remove the trailing `;` and then use the methods provided for you in the `Integer` class.

```
while ( fileReader.hasNextLine() ) {
    String line = fileReader.nextLine();
    if ( line.startsWith( "0x" ) ) {
        line = line.replace( ";", "" );
        List<Byte> wrapped = Arrays
                .asList( line.split( " " ) )
                .stream()
                // convert all the string representations to their Int value
                .map( Integer::decode )
                // convert all the Integer values to their byte value
                .map( Integer::byteValue )
                .collect( Collectors.toList() );
        // if you're OK with changing commands to a List<Byte[]>, you can skip this step
        byte[] toAdd = new byte[wrapped.size()];
        for ( int i = 0; i < toAdd.length; i++ ) {
            toAdd[i] = wrapped.get( i );
        }
        commands.add( toAdd );
    }
}
```

Comment: java.lang.Byte also has a `decode` method, saving you having to `map(Integer::byteValue)`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Thanks for the tip. Didn't realize that was there. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException rolled back to what I had before because I realized that `Byte::decode` throws an error for some of OP's sample data.